# Ionic 2 : Warn after "npm install"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic2

I use Ionic v2.1.8 and when I run the command "npm install" I have a lot of warn like this :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile>npm install
npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.8 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.2.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.2.0 requires a peer of zone.js@0.7.2 but none was installed.
```

My package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "codecov": "^2.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "AppFineMobile: An Ionic project"
}
```

I don't understand because I have these modules on my node_modules folder. And when I tried to install one of them, I keep the warn with another npm install.

I really don't understand and I don't know how to solve that

Comment: can you add your package.json? There must be dependancy issues

Comment: Sure. I have uptdate my post

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update all your `angular packages` to `2.4.8`.Also your `ionic-angular` package is `2.2.0`.

Change:

```
"@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.8",
```

Also

```
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"zone.js" :"0.7.2"
```

Clear your `node_modules` folder in case of issues and do:
`npm install`

Comment: Oh nice it's ok. But now I have 3 new error after npm install :
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.8
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.8
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.4.8
They are notified in red.